# Does the Swift compiler get rid of superfluous type casts when using a typealias?

Tags: swift

In my application I can't decide what floating point format will be the best for performance. Its not so much the matter of bits that I am worried about rather how it interfaces with various functions I am using since I am using math libraries and graphics libraries.

As a result I have built everything using `typealias EngineDecimal = CGFloat` so that at the end I can experiment with changing that to other formats such as GLFloat, Float32 etc.

My question is what does the compiler do if I write a function like this:

```
func foo(in: EngineDecimal)-> EngineDecimal
{
   return Decimal(mathFunction(CGFloat(in)));
}
//foo2 is a library defined function that I have no control over but I'm typing a sample one for this example
func foo2(in: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
   return sin(in) + cos(in)
}
```

Will the compiler notice if Decimal is the same type as CGFloat and thus get rid of the casting statements? So in essence would this code run faster if `typealias EngineDecimal = CGFloat` vs if `typealias EngineDecimal = GLFloat` ?

Comment: There is already a [Decimal type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal), so isn't this rather a silly choice of name?

Comment: `Decimal` is a built in Swift type as well, so it's quite a bad idea to use it as a typealias for `CGFloat`. Moreover, you have no casts in your question. For whether typealiases result in any performance benefits, no, they are handled compile time, so they can't provide any runtime benefits.

Comment: What's the motivation for this question? Are you experiencing actual slowness? If you have a serious "what's faster" question, don't ask; _test_.

Comment: Let me change the name I use

Comment: So this is mostly a theoretical question however I now know that it isn't a big deal

Comment: To follow up on @matt's comment: if you have a concern about compiler optimization and code generation, performance testing is but one of the tools at your disposal. Look at the generated assembly with and without your change, and you'll see if there are extra operations or extra calls, or if the compiler has optimized them away.

Answer (score 1):

A typealias doesn't create a new type, it just allows a new name to be used *in place* of an existing type. So there is no casting being done and no optimisation needs to occur.